# Is it possible to save a Selenium Screenshot to a PIL image object?

Tags: python, selenium, python-imaging-library

I have a slow computer where saving a large image like a screenshot takes 2-3 seconds. I don't need the image saved to my computer, I just need it as a PIL Image object. Is there anyway to do this without saving it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(link)
browser.save_screenshot('path/to/file')
new_img = Image.open('path/to/file')
# code that does stuff with image object
```

Comment: Saving to disk is probably not the time sink here.  If you have a low-end graphics card, reading from the screen takes a long time.  Graphics chips are optimized for streams going TO the frame buffer, not reads coming FROM the frame buffer.

Comment: There is a function called `get_screenshot_as_png` that should do it for you.

Comment: No I think that what he needs is an object to later use with PIL. I'm exactly trying to achieve that to later use it with Imagio.